# ORA-28040: No Authentication protocol

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, vpn

I am trying to connect to remote DB via simple JDBC but i am getting below

```
error:
 *** SQLException caught ***
ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
```

code :

```
import java.sql.*; 
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import java.io.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class JDBC {

public static void main (String args []) throws SQLException {
    try
    {

       //Connecting to Oracle server
    OracleDataSource ds = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
    ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@remotehostname:1521:dbname");
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection("my username", "my password");
    System.out.println("Connected to DB");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) { System.out.println ("\n*** SQLException 
 caught ***\n" + ex.getMessage());}
     catch (Exception e) {System.out.println ("\n*** other Exception  caught ***\n");}
 }
}
```

I have added ojdbc6.jar and all supporting jars to build path. I am able to connect to remote via VPN but not via JDBC .. any guidance much appreciated...

Comment: Which driver _version_ are you using? (the number in the jar file is the Java version it's intended for, not the driver version). I have seen this when using a 10.x driver against a 12.x database

Answer (score 1):

From [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006)
If the client version does not meet or exceed the value defined by SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER parameter(sqlnet.ora file), then authentication fails with an ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol error or an ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported error.

You can check your driver version using below command

```
$java -jar ojdbc6.jar -getversion
```

Try setting SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER in sqlnet.ora file to lower Oracle version like 8,9 or 10 .

Check this [issue](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/177075/after-upgrading-to-oracle-12c-database-i-start-get.html) for more info.